# Passing current controller's model to a component results in unresolved Promise Array in Ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to pass in my current context's model to a component. I'm using FIXTURE data in async mode, and while the promise resolves in the model hook and renders fine in my example's {{#each}} helper, when I try to pass this model's array to a component, it doesn't seem to pass the resolved promise but instead it passes the 
unresolved promise and the component's sort method errors out.

For example, here is my model and FIXTURES:

```
App.Forecast = DS.Model.extend({
 forecastName: DS.attr('string'),
 campaignId: DS.attr('string'),
 datapoints: DS.hasMany('datapoint',{ async: true }) 
});

App.Forecast.FIXTURES = [
{
 id: 1,
 forecastName: 'Winter holidays',
 campaignId: '123435',
 datapoints: [1,2,3,4]
},
...
];

App.Datapoint = DS.Model.extend({
 label: DS.attr('string'),
 value: DS.attr('number')
});

App.Datapoint.FIXTURES = [
{
 id: 1,
 label: "April",
 value: 50
}, {
 id: 2,
 label: "May",
 value: 100
},
...
];
```

When I click into the context of a single Forecast, this renders fine:

```
{{#each datapoints}}
  <li>{{label}}: {{value}} </li> 
{{/each}}
```

But when I try to pass the datapoints array to my component, it doesn't pass the resolved promise array:

```
{{data-sort forecastName=forecastName data=datapoints}}
```

Example in jsfiddle: 
[Does not work](http://jsfiddle.net/cheralyn/6SJv5/)

And here is a jsfiddle of what the output *should* look like (I cheat by passing a hard-coded array to the component instead):
[Works by cheating](http://jsfiddle.net/cheralyn/5rtXk/)

Thanks in advance